# Bayesian shrinkage doesn't affect eigenspace

Tags: bayesian, covariance

The book Machine Learning a Probabilistic Perspective by Kevin Murphy on page 130 states following fact without proof:

Consider the MLE estimate of covariance matrix $\Sigma_{\text{MLE}}$. The Bayesian based
shrinkage estimation is given by
$$
\Sigma_{\text{MAP}}(i,j)
=
\begin{cases}
\Sigma_{\text{MLE}}(i,j)\quad &\text{if}\ i=j, \\
(1-\lambda)\Sigma_{\text{MLE}}(i,j) &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
This will change the eigenvalues but will not affect the eigenvectors. It clearly seems to be not true because for $\lambda = 1$, $\Sigma_{\text{MAP}}$ is a diagonal matrix with eigenvectors given by columns of identity matrix. Has the book got this fact wrong?